# VBA - DAO Recordset: How to Identify the New Line Position

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I need to identify if a DAO recordset is positioned on the new line, once that it's AbsolutePosition doesn't change after AddNew, as BOF and EOF keeps the same.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.EditMode` property of `Recordset`.

`dbEditAdd     2    AddNew method invoked.`